# Next.js build error on Vercel but not in Local

Tags: next.js

So, I'm developing an app with Next and when I build on local everything runs smoothly, and the app is generated, but when I publish on Veercel, I get an error message and the build fails.

Message: `Module not found: Can't resolve '../@constants/Styles/General.css' in '/vercel/path0/pages'`

When I check the files they are linked correctly but is something that Vercel isn't able to link of work with.

[image]

Beside that the error message specifies something modules, but I'm not using them.

Comment: Anyone found the problem?

Comment: Make sure the casing in the path you use to import the file matches the actual path of the file in the filesystem. For example, make sure it's `'../@constants/Styles/General.css'` and not `'../@constants/styles/general.css'`, or similar.

Answer (score 9):

I also got this error when trying to import a local module / file.

I hadn't realised that the file I was importing was written with a capital letter and when I had *changed only the file name's casing, that change wasn't added to my commit*.

**To fix it, I had to run** `git mv -f Oldname newname` **and then commit that change.**

The issue occurs due to case-insensitive file systems allowing the local builds to pass (as the path is resolved) but the Vercel build step, being case-sensitive, does not pass.

Answer (score 1):

**It is usally git error**
Such as changing the case of files or folder names.You can either entirely remove .git folder or try changing cases of the error file

Answer (score -1):

add this in your next.config.js or ts
eslint: {
ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
},

Comment: you don't want to have this for the sake of safety of your project.